# bashから「操作を記録」で作成したworkflowを実行したい

Tags: automator

bashからコマンドでworkfiowを立ち上げたいのですが、
delay.workflowがディレクトリとして認識されてしまい実行できません。
解決方法をご相談したく存じます。

背景
OSX、Network Link Conditionerの設定を、自動で変更する機能を実装をしようとしています。
CLIで設定変更をする方法が不明なので、設定変更の動作とautomatorで自動化しました。
しかし、bashから実行できずに困っています。

delay.workflowを作成し、保存。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
下記のdelay.shを実行

```
#!/bin/bash -v
# @(#) 遅延投入のためのスクリプトです。
/Users/hoge/Desktop/app/delay.workflow
```

下記のエラーが発生し、workflowが実行できない

```
delay.sh: line 5: /Users/hoge/Desktop/app/delay.workflow: is a directory
```

そこで、下記のようにコードを書き換えてみました。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
# @(#) 遅延投入のためのスクリプトです。
Open /Users/hoge/Desktop/app/delay.workflow
```

エラーは表示されなくなりましたが、automatorでdelay.workflowの編集画面が開いてしまい
やはりワークフローは自動実行されません。

ワークフロー単体で動作させた際の動画がこちらです。
http://youtu.be/EE2SqXHQgUw

Comment: automator /Users/hoge/Desktop/app/delay.workflow とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: アクション“操作を記録”でエラーが起きました。が表示されました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

workflowをコマンドで動かしたい場合、
通常は@heliac2001さんのおっしゃるように
`automator /Users/hoge/Desktop/app/delay.workflow`で大丈夫ですが、
workflowにアクション"操作を記録"が入っている場合、
セキュリティの問題から
`アクション“操作を記録”でエラーが起きました。`
英語で`The action “Watch Me Do” encountered an error.`が出るそうです。

とりあえず、以下の設定で`マウス`が動き出すのを確認しましたが、
その後の過程で自分はPCのコンセントを抜かざるをえなくなったので
automatorで確認の上、自己責任でお願いいたします。

1. 設定画面→セキュリティ&プライバシー→アクセシビリティに「Terminal」を追加
2. 左下のロックを永久に解除(右下のAdvancedから真ん中のチェック項目をつければOK)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

内容を見ればわかるようにセキュリティ上非常に無防備な設定を行い、
初めてできるようになるので、apple scriptなど別手段を検討された方がよろしいかと存じます。
と思ったら[質問者様はすでに解決していらっしゃいました...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5593/applescript%E3%81%A7prefpane%E3%82%92%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8F)

Comment: セキュリティ的に危ないので、ブロックされているのですか・・・。いったいどこが間違っているのか・・・と途方に暮れていましたが、納得です。

（ご指摘の通り、AppleScriptもトライはしているのですが、中々一筋縄には動いてくれておりません・・・）