# AppleScriptでprefPaneを開く

Tags: macos, applescript

目的のシステム環境設定アイコンをクリックして
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Network Link Conditioner.prefPaneを開く
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

/Library/PreferencePanes/Network Link Conditioner.prefPane

この動作をAppleScriptで自動化したいです。

```
on run {input, parameters}

(* Your script goes here *)
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "Network Link Conditioner.prefPane"
end tell

return input
end run
```

このように書きましたが、

```
AppleScriptエラー (null)
error "" number -1721
```

が発生してしまっています。

> Harawoさま
>   ありがとうございます。
>   ご教示いただいた方法に基づき、最終的に下記のようにコードを修正し、動作を確認しました。

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set current pane to pane "com.apple.Network-Link-Conditioner"
end tell
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set current pane to pane "Network Link Conditioner"
```

ウインドウに表示されている名称を、そのまま利用するだけでいいはずです。ご確認のほどを。

あるいはインターナショナルなスクリプトにしようと思うのなら、IDを使う方法も考えていいかもしれません。

```
set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.general"
```

このスクリプトは、「一般」ペインを表示します。
IDを取得したいペインを表示しておき、

```
id of current pane
```

を実行すると、「結果」欄にIDが出力されます。